# what does mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId do

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, types, schema, objectid

what does this piece of code do?

```
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Role"
```

I didn't get what happens with the `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`
what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a schema type in mongoose
It is used as a primary key 
and the ref means that you have kept a reference of another model's document by using its primary key